# Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

please , i am trying for a week to find solution for this error

i am using tensorflow 1.0.0 
windows 10
cuda 8.0
cudnn 5.1

what is the reason of this error? i already decreased the batch size and still give me this error

it runs correctly on cpu but on gpu it gives me this error

please Help me

Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_event_mgr.cc:198] Unexpected Event status: 1

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot compare the test with CPU. You need to check if the computer has the necessary graphics card (GPU) support. Or, if you can ensure that the GPU not occupied during the runtime operation.